# On shared mail box, OfficeJS saveAsync() returns a draft ID that is not permitted by the owner's mailbox

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins, outlook-for-mac

**Version Affected:**

- OfficeJS 1.1.38
- Mac Outlook 16.34 (20020900)
  Note: This flow use to work up to about April 22, 2020 and this flow currently works on Windows Outlook and Outlook Web Access with our web-addin

**Issue:**

The Draft ID provided is not accessible by the mailbox owner on MS Graph service

**Message returned from Graph:**

- code: 404
- message: 404 ErrorInvalidMailboxItemId: "Item Id doesn't belong to the current mailbox."
- status: “failed”

**Steps to reproduce:**

Add a shared mailbox:

1. Find and Open a shared mailbox

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a new email in Outlook for Mac
2. In the From field, select the shared mailbox
3. Open and add-in's pane and try to call
   Office.context.mailbox.item.saveAsync()
4. Pass the result from `Office.context.mailbox.item.saveAsync()` to

```js
Office.context.mailbox.convertToRestId(
            results[0],
            Office.MailboxEnums.RestVersion.v1_0
          );
```

5. Use that ID to make a graph call with the mailbox owners graph token . The call errors out with the following message `404 ErrorInvalidMailboxItemId: "Item Id doesn't belong to the current mailbox."`

Comment: We are following up the same issue [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/1116).